# How do I specify which drive I mount onto Google Colab to use?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been mounting a specific Google Drive onto Colab for a few weeks using:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Suddenly today I tried to mount it again but a different Drive was mounted. The two drive are from separate Google accounts I use, and they are usually connected simultaneously on different windows on chrome browser.

I tried unmounting and remounting, but with no success. Is there a way to specifically tell Colab which Drive I want it to mount?

Answer (score 0):

The account used is determined by the account selected in the OAuth credential picker.

Related: a much simpler, automatic way to mount Drive is to use the UI in the file browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering though if there is a way to change the drive mounted after I've selected a drive through the OAuth credential picker.